Object reference not set to instance of object Plugin.BLE .NET MAUI
I am trying to develop an app that can connect to other devices using the current(running) device's bluetooth and send data. I am using Plugin.BLE, and whenever I am trying to connect to other devices it is encountering the following exception -
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
showData.xaml.cs
using InTheHand.Bluetooth;
using Plugin.BLE;
using Plugin.BLE.Abstractions;
using Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Contracts;
using Plugin.BLE.Abstractions.Exceptions;

using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;

namespace sample;

public partial class ShowData : ContentPage
{
  
    private List<IDevice> deviceList = new List<IDevice>();

    public ShowData(string cityLbl, string description, int pressure, int humidity, string countryName, int time_zone, bool clouds)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        city.Text = "City : " + cityLbl;
        desp.Text = "Weather Description : " + description;
        pres.Text = "Pressure : " + pressure.ToString();
        hum.Text = "Humidity : " + humidity.ToString();
        country.Text = "Country : " + countryName.ToString();
        time.Text = "Time : " + time_zone.ToString();

        clouds_data.Text = "Clouds : " + clouds.ToString();        
    }

    private async void btn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      
        var adapter =  CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter;
       if(adapter != null)
        {
            var systemDevices = adapter.GetSystemConnectedOrPairedDevices();

            var filteredDevices = systemDevices.Where(device => device.Name != null).ToList();

            ScanFilterOptions filterOptions = new ScanFilterOptions();

            var deviceList = filteredDevices.Select(device => device.Name);
            
            if (systemDevices.Count > 0 && systemDevices != null)
            {
                string deviceNames = string.Join(", ", deviceList.Select(device => device));
                await DisplayAlert("Devices", deviceNames, "Ok");

                var device = systemDevices[0];

                try
                {
                    Guid service_id = filterOptions.ServiceUuids[0];

                    Guid serviceUUID = service_id;
     

                    if (device.IsConnectable)
                    {
                        await adapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(device);

                        await DisplayAlert("Success", $"Connected to {device}!", "Ok");

                        var services = await device.GetServicesAsync();

                        foreach (var service in services)
                        {
                            var characteristic = await service.GetCharacteristicAsync(Guid.Parse("d8de624e-140f-4a22-8594-e2216b84a5f2"));

                            string msg = "Hello";
                            byte[] msgBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);

                            characteristic.WriteAsync(msgBuffer);
                            await DisplayAlert("Sent", "Message sent successfully!", "Ok");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await DisplayAlert("Error", "Device is not connectable!", "Ok");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Exception", $"{ex.Message}", "Ok");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("No Devices", "No Bluetooth devices found", "Ok");
            }
        }
       else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("No Devices", "Null adapter", "Ok");
        }
    }
}

AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE" />
</manifest>

I have also check for external permissions before starting the connecting process , it is displaying the available devices names as well.
Help appreciated!

Which line causes the exception?  What does the stack trace show?

@Jason I added few breakpoints and found that
await adapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(device);
was now giving GattCallbackError : 238
However, the device is properly shown!
Thanks!
